# How to customise the default Activity in React Native apart from the default name "MainActivity"?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, kotlin

I tried to configure a different Default Launcher activity say `AuthActivity`, which is different from the default `MainActivity`. But it always launches the `MainActivity`.
I tried to set `AuthActivity` as default activity in Manifest and renamed `MainActivity` as `HomeActivity`. But I get the following error :

> Error type 3 Error: Activity class
>   {/.MainActivity} does not exist.

```java
<activity android:name=".AuthActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

```java
<activity android:name=".HomeActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

How do I configure a Native activity to be the Launcher Activity and then launch the Activity to load the Javascript files?

Comment: Did you try a clean of the project?

Comment: Yes, I did. No luck

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default React Native executes the `MainActivity` if you don't tell it to do something different. Try to launch your app with :

```
react-native run-android --main-activity AuthActivity
```